# Spring MVC Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contrato'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Tenho uma página "list.jsp" que renderiza a lista de determinada entidade. Me pediram pra criar um formulário de pesquisa dentro dessa página:

```html
<form:form role="form" commandName="contrato" servletRelativeAction="/contrato/search" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="estabelecimento">
        <spring:message code="estabelecimento" />
      </label>
      <form:select id="estabelecimentos" class="form-control" path="estabelecimento">
        <form:option value="-1" label="-- Selecione --" />
        <form:options items="${estabelecimentos}" itemLabel="nomeFantasia" itemValue="id" />
      </form:select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <spring:message code="pesquisar" />
  </button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
    <spring:message code="limpar" />
  </button>
</form:form>
```

Meu Controller está assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam(required = false) Estabelecimento estabelecimento, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", required = false) int page) {
    ...
}
```

Com o `<form:select>` apresenta a exceção abaixo, porém se eu fizer a pesquisa com uma String, descrição por exemplo (mudando um pouco o método search) funciona. Podem me dar uma luz?

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contrato'